# Stop Sticky Sidebar before footer

Tags: jquery

That's my script where I created the mess in the else if:

```
$( window ).on('load resize', function(){
    var $sidebar   = $(".sidebar_container"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 130;


    $window.scroll(function() {
        if (($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) && (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)').matches)) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else if (($window.scrollTop() + offset.top + $(".sidebar_container").height()) > ($window.scrollTop() + $(".main-footer").height())){
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top - $(".main-footer").height()
            });
        }else{
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
        
    });
});
```

Comment: I would recommend the sticky-sidebar plugin https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/ -- likely you will be calculating footer top, window y + sidebar height, and then applying CSS to the sidebar to position at the bottom of it's scrollable area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, for everybody who stuck on the same...
It wasn't working because the first if handle needs to be the last possible statment in this progress. Here to stop at the bottom.

If someone want to use a smooth sidebar with positioning absolute...
Works like a charm now.

```
$( window ).on('load resize', function(){
    var $sidebar   = $(".sidebar_container"),
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 130,
        footerHeight = $(".main-footer").innerHeight();


    $window.scroll(function() {
// 300 is just to catch the point before completly reach the bottom , change or delete
        if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > ($(document).height() - footerHeight + 300)) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
// 45 is just needed in px on my layout, you can change or delete it
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - footerHeight - 45
            });
            }
//erase && to use on all viewports
        else if (($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) && (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)').matches)){
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
            }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need all this hassle. Just use css `position: sticky;` and you are good to go.

Check details here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning

Comment: Thanks for your response, but thats not what i asked for. Position sticky isn‘t an Option in this case.